# While developing a voice agent, I am using axios to get data from a spreadsheet. However, I cannot get all data at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, actions-on-google

I am new to voice agents and particularly to Javascript. However, I am in need to develop a voice agent in the Google Actions Console.

The most critical part of my agent is that I need to read data from a google spreadsheet which I figure out I can use SheetDB, a web service, to stream the data from the spreadsheet to the web. Right now the stream is running on the following link: https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/n3ol4hwmfsmqd

I am also setting up a webhook to retrieve the data from the stream through cloud functions in firebase. This is the cloud function as I have it right now:

```
const { conversation } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = conversation({debug: true});

app.handle('getItem', conv => {

    getItem();
    conv.add("This test to see if we are accessing the webhook");
});

function getData() {
    return axios.get('https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/n3ol4hwmfsmqd');
}

function getItem() {
    getData().then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
    });
}

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

What I am trying to do here is that in the conversation, I call the getItem() function which basically, read the data and print it to the console. the getData() function uses axios plugin to read from SheetDB.

However, when I run the agent and the data is read from my function the data is split into multiple log messages. THis is the console log in cloud function:

```
2:04:27.925 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
Function execution took 378 ms, finished with status code: 200 
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
[ { Item: 'Beam B-1',
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
Level: '2',
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
Zone: 'A',
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
Location: 'Beam B-1 is located on Level 2 in zone A',
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
Responsible: 'Contractor' },
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
{ Item: 'Column C-2',
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
Level: '3',
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
Zone: 'A',
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
Location: 'Column C-2 is located on Level 3 in zone A',
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
Responsible: 'Kiewit' },
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
{ Item: 'Window B',
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
Level: '2',
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
Zone: 'B',
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
Location: 'Window B is located on Level 2 in zone B',
2:04:30.645 PM
cf-hfyNV-ZVWlECkylj8TUN1w-name
Responsible: 'Tech' } ]
```

The complete data looks like this:

```
[{"Item":"Beam B-1","Level":"2","Zone":"A","Location":"Beam B-1 is located on Level 2 in zone A","Responsible":"Contractor"},{"Item":"Column C-2","Level":"3","Zone":"A","Location":"Column C-2 is located on Level 3 in zone A","Responsible":"Kiewit"},{"Item":"Window B","Level":"2","Zone":"B","Location":"Window B is located on Level 2 in zone B","Responsible":"Tech"}]
```

The problem is that I need to read the data at once, in other words, should be printed in a single log to be able to parse it and retrieve the piece of data I need.

I have struggled with this for some time so I hope anybody can help me. Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks a bit correct, although you need to consider how you are using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). They are asynchronous, which means that code below the async operation can run even before the first operation is done.

So when you run `getItem()` and then `conv.add`, you aren't guaranteed to have completed your DB operation. This is where [`async`/`await` keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) are used, which can make it a bit easier to manage asynchronous operations in a sequential way.

Another issue is more directly related to your logging. By default Firebase Functions will break up results into separate lines as you see. There is [more documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs) on how to use their own logging SDK or how to fix the logging issue directly.

With these two in mind, here's a slightly updated version of your code which should run as expected.

```js
const { conversation } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
require('firebase-functions/lib/logger/compat'); // console.log compat
const axios = require('axios');

const app = conversation({debug: true});

app.handle('getItem', async conv => {
    const data = await getItem();
    conv.add("This test to see if we are accessing the webhook");
});

function getData() {
    // This returns a Promise
    return axios.get('https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/n3ol4hwmfsmqd');
}

async function getItem() {
    const res = await getData()
    console.log(res.data);
    return data // To use in your Action's response
}

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: This worked great! Thank you so much! I have other problems now but this responds my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Firebase Functions and maybe this is the way they present their logs?

Have you tried accessing the data inside ***res.data*** already?

I don't see why you won't be able to "have it all" inside it and manipulate/access anything you want. Your code seems ok.

Ah, because you're new to JavaScript I think it's important to highlight that what you have (the response) is an **array of objects**.

So pay attention sometimes it can be tricky accessing the properties inside it.